# Radial Grid Search Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, grid, radial

I'm sure there's a clean way to do this, but I'm probably not using the right keywords for find it.

So let's say I have a grid. Starting from a position on the grid, return all of the grid coordinates that fall within a given distance. So I call something like:

```
getCoordinates( currentPosition, distance )
```

And for each coordinate, starting from the initial position, add all cardinal directions, and then add the spaces around those and so forth until the distance is reached. I imagine that on a grid this would look like a diamond. The function would return that array of coordinates. Can someone point me to a routine that will do this efficiently ( I'm working in AS3, for what it's worth )?

In the desired output, iteration 1 would be:

```
.x.
xxx
.x.
```

Iteration 2 would be:

```
..x..
.xxx.
xxxxx
.xxx.
..x..
```

Iteration 3:

```
...x...
..xxx..
.xxxxx.
xxxxxxx
.xxxxx.
..xxx..
...x...
```

and so on...

Comment: Clarification attempted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: Updated the algorithm to reflect what the OP wanted.

Iteration 1:

```
.x.
xxx
.x.
```

Iteration 2:

```
..x..
.xxx.
xxxxx
.xxx.
..x..
```

...
Iteration 4:

```
....x....
...xxx...
..xxxxx..
.xxxxxxx.
xxxxxxxxx
.xxxxxxx.
..xxxxx..
...xxx...
....x....
```

Clearly, you can determine the coordinates without iterating.

If the starting point is (X, Y), and the iteration is n

```
for(int i = x - n; i <= x + n; i++)
{
    for(int j = y - n; j <= y + n; j++)
    {
        int dx = abs(i - x);
        int dy = abs(j - y);
        if(dx + dy <= n) //Produces a diamond, n+1 would produce a diamond with cut corners
        {
            //The point at (i, j) is within the marked area.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends what kind of data structure you're using to represent your grid, but generally a [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) should take care of this for you.

Comment: In this case there is no data structure. I'm just using coordinates (X/Y). I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

BFS + FIFO queue:

```
P = U = 0;
Q[P] = currentPosition;
D[ Q[P] ] = 0; D[~all the rest~] = infinity (or really any flag, such as -1)

while ( P <= U )
{
  current = Q[P];
  ++P;

  for ( each neighbor N = (X', Y') of (current.X, current.Y) )
    if ( D[N] == inf && D[current] + 1 <= distance )
    {
      D[N] = D[current] + 1;

      ++U;
      Q[U] = N;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities, depending on what kins of distance you want and how much programming you are willing to do:

(1) Dijkstra's [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). If you imagine that each two neighboring points on you grid are connected (only vertical and horizontal connections, so each point has 4 neighbors), you'll get your diamond. You don't have to implement any data structure for the graph -- you only need to generate lists of neighbors for current vertex, as you go.

(2) [Fast marching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_marching_method). This'll give you true Euclidean distance within the numerical error, so you'll get an approximate circle, not a diamond.

Answer (score 0):

For Iteration N, you want all points P' such that distance from P to P' <= N, where distance is |X' - X| + |Y' - Y|.

```
for (int i = -N; i <= N; i++)
   for (int j = abs(i) - N; j <= N - abs(i); j++)
   {
      results.Add(new Point(X+i, Y+j));
   }
}

return results;
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this question is 9 years old, but an algorithm that actually iterates radially from the centre (in a diamond) would look like:

```
for (int mag = 0; mag <= range; ++mag)
    for (int xm = 0; xm <= mag; ++xm)
    {
        int ym = mag - xm;
        int xms = (xm == 0) ? -1 : 1;
        int yms = (ym == 0) ? -1 : 1;
        for (int xs = -1; xs <= xms; xs += 2)
            for (int ys = -1; ys <= yms; ys += 2)
            {
                int x = x_centre + xm * xs;
                int y = y_centre + ym * ys;
                // Do whatever with x, y here
            }
    }
```